# Redirecting to without .html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So I have already this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Now if someone enters:

example.com/test.html

how can I redirect him to:

example.com/test

i tried:

```
redirect /test.html /test
```

but it gave me Page is not redirecting properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another rule. Replace your current rule with this and see how it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```